XAMPP PHP EXEC function provides different output when executing from browser and CLI
I am working on project where i need to execute jar file with PHP, i am using php exec function to execute jar file, When i am executing my php script from browser i am getting expected output, but when executing from command line i am getting error "Unable to access jarfile wrapper.jar".
My php script having following code :
exec("java -jar wrapper.jar $arr[0] $arr[1] $arr[2] $arr[3] $arr[4] $arr[5] $arr[6] $arr[7] $arr[8] $arr[9]",$output);

PHP script and jar file wrapper.jar both are in same directory, Please check output below :

When executed from browser
Array ( [0] => REFNUM : 1258740043092402176 [1] => ANumber : null [2] => Status : y [3] => Txn : cf77bd77-f365-475f-b9ba-814f16f3a123 )


which is expected output

When executed from command line
Error: Unable to access jarfile wrapper.jar
OUTPUT: Array
(
)


as it is CLI, i also change my code to provide absolute path to jar file as per below :
exec("java -jar 'D:\xampp\htdocs\AVAULT\wrapper.jar' $arr[0] $arr[1] $arr[2] $arr[3] $arr[4] $arr[5] $arr[6] $arr[7] $arr[8] $arr[9]",$output);

i got following output :
Error: Unable to access jarfile wrapper.jar OUTPUT: Array ( )

I have also checked exec('java -version',$output), it shows me correct java version installed on my system on both browser and command line
I have also noticed when used single quote and double quotes in exec function it behaves differently
with double quotes (in broswer)
exec("java -jar wrapper.jar $arr[0] $arr[1] $arr[2] $arr[3] $arr[4] $arr[5] $arr[6] $arr[7] $arr[8] $arr[9]",$output);

output :
 Array ( [0] => REFNUM : 1258740043092402176 [1] => ANumber : null [2] => Status : y [3] => Txn : 01bac91a-9dd5-4886-9ca1-2166233af827 )

with single quotes (in broswer)
exec('java -jar wrapper.jar $arr[0] $arr[1] $arr[2] $arr[3] $arr[4] $arr[5] $arr[6] $arr[7] $arr[8] $arr[9]',$output);

output :
Array ( [0] => ERROR : MISMATCH_AC_SA [1] => Status : n [2] => ANumber : Null [3] => Txn : ec883e3f-e8e7-4feb-ac37-9ce9f36d3d0b )

I don't know why different behavior whith single and double quotes.
However my actual requirement is to execute jar file from php command line.
I am really confused

Why while executing jar file from command line which is in same directory as php script, i got unable access jar file error even with absolute path to jar file
Why exec function behaves differently with single quotes and double quotes


Hint: try echo "\xa";.

It sound like a permissions issue to me, but I'm not familiar with PHP in the Windows environment. The quotes issue is simple, see: What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?

@Olivier, can you elaborate ?

Did you try the echo?

@Olivier, did you mean exec("echo '\xa'",$out1);  ? i got following output
Array(  [0] => ')

Just execute the echo statement in a test script, nothing more.

I don't get it either. All it does is a linefeed: https://3v4l.org/WGffT Why does the question require a linefeed? Why not say something concrete instead of hinting?

@KIKOSoftware Indeed. Now look at this: "D:\xampp\htdocs\AVAULT\wrapper.jar". Got it?

No, I don't.  Is this some Windows command line thing?

@KIKOSoftware I thought it was obvious. You need to escape backslashes: "D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AVAULT\\wrapper.jar"

@Olivier Yes, indeed, you need to do that. Never thought of it....

Another issue is that there are extra single quotes. The correct command line is java -jar some.jar, not java -jar 'some.jar'.

@Olivier from command line i have to use absolute path, so have to put absolute path to jar file in single quotes

No, you don't need to put single quotes for an absolute path.

But you need to escape a backslash in a PHP string. So "\" instead of "". See: Strings. It says: "To specify a literal backslash, double it (\).".

@Olivier,@KIKO Software, Yes you are right, actually i have to do both, remove single quotes around jar file path and have to escape backslashes D:\xampp\htdocs\AVAULT\wrapper.jar, and it worked from both CLI and browser, Thank you both of you.

That's good to hear. If nobody writes an actual answer to your question, which I think Oliver is best suited to do, you can also write the answer yourself. Unanswered question tend to fade into oblivion after a while. That is, if you care about such things.

@KIKOSoftware, Sure will do

With help of commenters, i was able to solve issue.
You must be aware that using php command line, paths must be absolute, below piece of code works for me. Please note that it is necessary to escape backslashes
exec("java -jar D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AVAULT\\wrapper.jar $arr[0] $arr[1] $arr[2] $arr[3] $arr[4] $arr[5] $arr[6] $arr[7] $arr[8] $arr[9]",$output);

Please note that if you are passing any php variables in exec function do not use single quotes, for example :
exec('java -jar D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AVAULT\\wrapper.jar $arr[0] $arr[1] $arr[2] $arr[3] $arr[4] $arr[5] $arr[6] $arr[7] $arr[8] $arr[9]',$output);

using single quotes php variable will be treated as string,you will get unexpected output, more detail about single and double quotes in PHP can be found here
